# Cross-Origin Request Blocked error for get request API

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

I have a problem with a fetch on an API, here is my code:

```
const OPTIONS = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-Auth-Token': process.env.FOOT_KEY,
  }
};

export async function setLeagues() {
  const countries = [
    {
      name: "Ligue 1",
      leagues_id: 2015
    },
    {
      name: "Premier League",
      leagues_id: 2021,
    },
    {
      name: "Bundesliga 1",
      leagues_id: 2002,
    },
    {
      name: "Primera Division",
      leagues_id: 2014,
    },
  ]

  let allLeagues = [];

  for (const country of countries) {
    const { name, leagues_id } = country;
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/${leagues_id}`,
      OPTIONS
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    allLeagues.push(data);
  }

  return {
    type: "SET_LEAGUES",
    payload: allLeagues
  }
}
```

But I have a console error :

[image: console error]

However when I make the request with postman the returned response contains well:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.

Finally the error seems to be present only on firefox but not on chrome.

I try to fetch this API : football-data.org/docs/v2/index.html#_cors_handling, who is CORS enabled.

Thanks you for your help !

Comment: try adding CORS headers

Comment: Can you specify please ? ^^

Comment: You mean : mode: 'cors' ?
if, yes this is the default settings, and anyway i try but that don't work.

Comment: You probably want to update the question to make it clear that you know the documentation for that API indicates it’s CORS-enabled. You can cite the URL for the part of the docs a https://www.football-data.org/docs/v2/index.html#_cors_handling. And given that the API is CORS-enabled, it’s odd that you’d be getting a CORS error when calling it, and also odd that you’d only get the error in Firefox

Comment: In Firefox, what’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than 200 OK success response?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers, there is no error in the network ... All the request have 200 state.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, thanks for your answer but like the author says : "This question is not about how to fix a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'..." error". I looked at the link he offered but I found nothing relevant to my question.

Comment: I suggest you self-delete this question. Disabling AdBlock and other extensions is already a well-known and well-documented troubleshooting step for CORS errors. This question and the answer aren’t really useful to future readers, because they don’t add anything new to the existing knowledge in this area.

Comment: Ok it's really weird: The problem is actually not resolved. it worked for a while but without changing anything it caused me the same error and impossible to find the solution. Sometimes the fetch works and sometimes he doesn't and I have this error. However, my requests are always 200.

Answer (score -1):

this might be more work, but when I had a similar issue this is what I used. 
I would recommend using cors-anywhere. Essentially you would host your own version of the service and make your requests using cors-anywhere as a proxy. Cors-anywhere will add the necessary headers and handle cors for you.

https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Also once you have it running, make sure to set you env vars so you only allow traffic coming from your website. I will look something like this: export CORSANYWHERE_WHITELIST=https://example.com